# WPF Grid Faded in on Top of Other Grids Has Inactive Controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior with a UI I'm working on for a C# WPF application.

The cliffnotes version is that I have 3 Grids that all "inhabit" the same area on the form.  Based on some toggle buttons those grids are enabled or disabled and faded in and out of view.  However, it seems that in some cases certain TextBoxes can be used and others cannot.

Here is the style I'm applying:

```
    <!-- Fade in/out style for grid -->
    <Style
        x:Key="FadeInOutStyle"
        TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger
                Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="True">
                <Trigger.Setters>
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                        Value="1"/>
                </Trigger.Setters>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="0.0"
                                To="1.0"
                                Duration="0:0:0.8"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1.0"
                                To="0.0"
                                Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger
                Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="False">
                <Trigger.Setters>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                        Value="0"/>
                </Trigger.Setters>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

The style seems to apply just fine, the grids fade into and out of view as expected.  Here's one of the "checked" functions that enables the checked grid and disables the others.  If you want to see the rest just say so, but it would be a bit dog and pony show:

```
    private void IndividualRadio_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TwoIndividualGrid.IsEnabled = false;
        this.CommercialGrid.IsEnabled = false;
        this.IndividualGrid.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

And here is the XAML for one of the grids.  They all have nothing more than labels and TextBox controls.  They all start with the same margins and similar dimmensions:

```
        <Grid
            Name="IndividualGrid"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Height="30"
            Width="420"
            Opacity="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10,90,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource FadeInOutStyle}"
            Panel.ZIndex="0">
            <Label
                Content="First Name"
                Height="25"
                Width="90"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox
                Name="SubjFirstNameBox"
                Height="30"
                Width="100"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource ValidationStyle}"
                Margin="100,0,0,0">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding 
                        Path="SubjFirstName" 
                        Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Label
                Content="Last Name"
                Height="25"
                Width="90"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="210,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox
                Name="SubjLastNameBox"
                Height="30"
                Width="100"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource ValidationStyle}"
                Margin="310,0,0,0">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding 
                        Path="SubjLastName" 
                        Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
```

And, just because I know someone might ask to see it, here are a couple examples of the properties I've binded.  In this case, the First Name/SubjFirstName textbox does not work but the Last Name/SubjLastName textbox does:

```
    private string subjFirstName;
    public string SubjFirstName
    {
        get { return subjFirstName; }
        set { subjFirstName = value; }
    }

    private string subjLastName;
    public string SubjLastName
    {
        get { return subjLastName; }
        set { subjLastName = value; }
    }
```

So, does anyone see what I'm messing up here?  I'm assuming it has to be the stacked grids, so if someone has a better approach I'd love to hear it.  I'm fairly certain I've done it this way before though, and I'd think that disabling and setting the panel index would do the trick.

Comment: So far i can see on the first view, you miss to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` (`using System.ComponentModel`) and add `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        ///<summary>
        /// Notify the UI for changes
        ///</summary>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }` also u need to add for example `OnPropertyChanged("SubjLastName")` to the setter.

Comment: I actually do need to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged in my view model, but for the moment that isn't affecting the other fields.  I'm just designing the UI for now.  I've also seen the error associated with missing that and it wouldn't be causing my issue in this case.

Comment: Can you refine what you mean when you say that 'certain TextBoxes can be used and others cannot' ? Are they completely non-functional/not accepting input, or is there something amiss with the bindings, or ...?

Comment: Sure.  On mouse-over the mouse cursor does not turn into a text cursor and I cannot click into the field to shift keyboard focus to it.  The field may as well be a picture rather than a textbox.

Comment: Qualifier to answer selected below - the answer is in the comments.  Key was to hook onto `Visibility` rather than trying to use `IsEnabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo, after an deeper view, i found now the following things which in my mind can cause this bug.

```
<TextBox Name="SubjLastNameBox" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ValidationStyle}" Margin="310,0,0,0">
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="SubjLastName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

As you can see i added `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` this is really important if you use `Mode="TwoWay"`. Also, as described in my comment you need to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your view-model.

```
//using System.ComponentModel;

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _subjLastName;

    ///<summary>
    /// public lastname property
    ///</summary>
    public string SubjLastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _subjLastName;
        }
        set
        {
            // The if statement here is importent! So you only raise the notification if the value has changed
            if (_subjLastName != value)
            {
                _subjLastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SubjLastName");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotify

    #region OnPropertyChanged + Handler

    ///<summary>
    /// PropertyChanged event handler
    ///</summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    ///<summary>
    /// Notify the UI for changes
    ///</summary>
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

EDIT:
Another solution might be:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Trigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Trigger.Setters>
</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
    <Trigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger.Setters>
</Trigger>
```

Here i use `Property="Visibility"` instead of `Property="Panel.ZIndex"` so you hide the complete control if it's not used or you show it if it's used. (You have to tune it a bit because you want to show the fade? If so, you need to bring it back to `Visible` before you begin to fade it in. Also you have to `Collapse` it after the fade out.)

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I will give it a shot when I get back in and report back.  This issue isn't intermittent and isn't affecting the other textbox controls on the form, just the stacked ones where I have multiple grids overlapping.

Comment: I added another solution based on the `Trigger`, in the example `Trigger` i use `Visibility` instead of `Panel.ZIndex` this might bring the wished effect.

Comment: Visibility did the trick.  I swear I've done this with `IsEnabled` before, but no dice this time.  Thanks for the suggestion.